# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:57997/Home/Get

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

When I try to access WebApi from MVC, I get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:57997/Home/Get. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64035' is therefore not allowed acces
```

**Service.Js**

```
app.service('MyService', function ($http) {

  var ApiAddress = "http://localhost:57997/";

  this.GetWebData = function () {
    var Getdatas= $http({
      url: ApiAddress + 'Home/Get',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      params: JSON.stringify(),
      content:{'content-type' :'application/Json'}
    })
    return Getdatas;
  }
});
```

**Controller.Js**

```
app.controller('WebCtrls', function ($scope,MyService) {
  $scope.Hello = "Hello angular How r u...";

  $scope.GetDb = function () {
    alert('Hello..');
    var SerData = MyService.GetWebData();
    SerData.then(function (d) {
      $scope.Emp = d.data;
    })
  }
})
```

**WebApi**

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    var x = prod.GetEmployees();
    return new JsonResult { Data = x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

**Global.asax**

in WebApi global file I wrote bellow code for cross page origin

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    string[] allowedOrigin = new string[] { "http://localhost:57997/" };
    var origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];
    if (origin != null && allowedOrigin.Contains(origin))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
        //Need to add more later , will see when required
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message clearly states that the origin is `http://localhost:64035`. The resource is at `http://localhost:57997/`. Port 64035 is trying at do a cross origin access to port 57997. Also `OPTIONS` should be an allowed method.

Comment: soo how to overcome this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it by disabling web security option of chrome browser by following command from the folder location where chrome.exe is present. First close all instances of chrome. Then run following command

> chrome.exe --disable-web-security

You can handle it at server side while filtering all request coming to server, add the header to response like this.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
```

Comment: Your this line 
"string[] allowedOrigin = new string[] { "http://localhost:57997/" };" 
 should be like this string[] allowedOrigin = new string[] { "http://localhost:64035/" };